# I got bad performance of request with timestamp field as flag?

Tags: laravel, postgresql

On laravel 8 app I have a table defined as with 2 timestamp fields which used not only as datetime value, but also as
a flag "published/not published":

```
        Schema::create('news', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title',255);
            ...
            $table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('postponed_published_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->softDeletes();

    ...
            $table->index(['postponed_published_at', 'published_at', 'title'], 'news_postponed_published_at_published_at_title_index');
        });
```

I run request :

```
$news = News::query()
    ->whereNull('published_at')
    ->whereRaw("postponed_published_at = '" . $this->day . "' ")
->get();
```

and I check explain of the request :

```
explain   SELECT *
    FROM "news"
    WHERE "published_at" is null     AND postponed_published_at = '2023-06-24 00:00:00'      AND "news"."deleted_at" is null


Seq Scan on news  (cost=0.00..5.78 rows=1 width=485)
  Filter: ((published_at IS NULL) AND (deleted_at IS NULL) AND (postponed_published_at = '2023-06-24 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
```

This scan results seems not good for me from point of performance...
Can it be done in some better way for latest version of mysql/postgres ?

Comment: I do not see any issue.. I have no idea what `cost` is (and if 5.78 is high or not).

Comment: A cost of 5 is tiny. If you are going to ask performance questions @mstdmstd then we need to know the number of rows in the table, the number of null/non null values for the columns involved and the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) for this statement? That gives you many details about the plan and the execution of the query. Just a plan is not enough. The ddl for the tables and indexes involved would be helpful as well

Comment: If you are not hapoy with query performance, then create an index to speed it up.

Comment: 1) Limit your question tags to one database either `MySQL` or `Postgres`.  2) You have not demonstrated an issue. Run `explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)` to get a better view of the query. 3) Where is `(deleted_at IS NULL)` coming from? To your question add the table definition.

Comment: How are `postponed_published_at` and `published_at` related?  (Can they be combined into a single column?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this index:

```
INDEX(published_at, deleted_at, postponed_published_at)
```

The order of the columns does not matter for *this* query.  Let's see your similar queries; there may be a better ordering.

More on index creation:  [*Index Cookbook*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) and note that `IS NULL` optimizes like `=`, but `IS NOT NULL` works differently.